# Object shows flickering/visual artifacts in material preview and render view

Tags: animation, 3d-view

[image: Distorted view]

Object shows flickering in material preview and render view

Comment: May i suggest to check your graphics card driver for an eventual update. Maybe even reinstalling Blender may help, it looks to me like some GPU related problem, especially so since you mention that it shows up in material preview and rendered mode.

Comment: may be i have changed some settings ? coz, it was working properly earlier